# call a function from inside a table that's inside another table in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

I am attempting to build my first game using love2D, I have hit a problem.

The game is a bubble popping game, I want to assign a bubble to each letter on the keyboard so that when a letter is pressed, the bubble will pop.

I have an external file called "bubble.lua" which I have tried to make an object "bubble" with.
to do that I have created a table "bubble" in the bubble.lua which contains functions and variables. Now, this file works when called from main.lua using just one bubble, however I am going to need 26 bubbles so I thought it would be best to store each bubble in another table. For the purpose of trying this I just stored one bubble using 1 as the key.This is where I have problems.

```
require "bubble"
local bubbles = {}
function love.load()
    bubbles[1] = bubble.load(100, 100)
end
function love.draw()
    for bubble in bubbles do
        bubble.draw()
    end
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    bubbles[key].bubble.pop()
end
```

Firstly, I know that the for loop in `love.draw()` does not work, and the line "bubble[key].bubble.pop" seems to return `nil` as well

The for loop I can probably find the solution myself online, my main problem is the "bubble[key].bubble.pop()" line, I cannot work out what's wrong or how to fix it.

Can anybody help me?

You may want to look at this as well:

bubble.lua

```
bubble = {}
function bubble.load(posX, posY)
    bubble.x = posX
    bubble.y = posY
    bubble.popped = false
end

function bubble.draw()

    if not bubble.popped then
        love.graphics.rectangle("line", bubble.x, bubble.y, 37, 37)
    else
        love.graphics.rectangle("line", bubble.x, bubble.y, 37, 100)
    end
end

function bubble.pop()
    bubble.popped = true
end
```

### Edit:

Following the advice of the answer below I now have the following error when I press "a":

> main.lua:14: attempt to index a nil value

the updated code is below

main.lua

```
require "bubble"
local bubbles = {}
function love.load()
    bubbles["a"] = bubble.load(100, 100)
end
function love.draw()
    for key, bubble in pairs(bubbles) do
       bubble.draw()
    end
end

function love.keypressed(key)
    bubbles[key].pop()
end
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Is the argument to `love.keypressed` a string or a number? The key `[1]` is the number one. The string `"1"` will not load the value at that index `1`. You need `tonumber` to convert or similar. Also your `bubble.pop` function is setting `popped` on the global `bubble` table not on any specific bubble "object". Similarly `bubble.draw` is operating on the global `bubble` table and not on a bubble "object".

Comment: `bubble.load` doesn't return any value, so you are not storing anything in the table. Also, you seem to be using OO not correctly as you are not creating different instances of bubbles; you are simply storing everything in exactly the same instance, which is not going to work.

Comment: how do i create a new instance of the bubble? and what should i be returning the bubble table from bubble.load?

Comment: Reading chapters on [OOP](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) and [classes](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with this code. First, you index by number when you initialize bubbles (`bubbles[1]`), but access them using the `key` as the index (`bubbles[key]`), which is NOT a number. You need to settle on one mechanism to index the bubbles. Let's say you picked using key as the index (instead of the number).

This loop:

```
for bubble in bubbles do
    bubble.draw()
end
```

should be written as:

```
for key, bubble in pairs(bubbles) do
    bubble.draw()
end
```

and instead of `bubbles[key].bubble.pop()` you can simply do `bubbles[key].pop()` as `bubbles[key]` already returns the bubble you can pop.

To initialize, instead of `bubbles[1]` you need to do `bubbles['a']` (or whatever other value is used by `key` in `love.keypressed(key)`).

Comment: thanks, i wonder if you know of a way i could problematically assign a bubble to each letter? rather than doing "bubbles['a'] = bubble.load() bubbles['b']=bubble.load()" etc.

Comment: You may try something like `for k = string.ord('a'), string.ord('z') do bubbles[string.char(k)] = bubble.load() end`.

Comment: i have edited the question to show my new code. i am getting an "attempt to index a nil value" error at "bubbles[key].pop()"

Comment: I just checked in the debugger and the value of `key` in `love.keypressed` is `a` when `a` is pressed. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @JamieMcAllister, you bubble.load doesn't return any value, and as the result you don't store anything in the table.